# Import list of urls for Google custom search "Sites to search"

Tags: api, google-custom-search

I want to import my bookmark urls from my google account in an automated way . Afterwards I can use google custom search through my bookmarks contents.

I looked for some api for google custom search to manipulate the "Sites to search" list but the only api I could find is :
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/search/customsearch/v1/
which is only for the actual search and not for manipulating the search sites.
Is there any existing solution to this?